# show system UI in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I activate show layout decoration in version 2021.2.1 of Android studio?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean source code?

Comment: No, in layout xml

Comment: Split may give you what you need

Comment: Palette at right side may give you decorations

Comment: In the coordinator layout I could not see the 'view options' icon. But when I used the constraint layout, the icon reappeared.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Coordinator layout, the 'view options' icon is removed, and you can see the system UI from 'layout validation'.

[image]